# Is there a way to distinguish or delete records which are duplicate in certain conditions only in Bigquery SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was working on a certain project which involves Hotel supervision and I am using Bigquery SQL to manage my database.

Say I have this table :

[image]

the goal is that a hotel should be supervised once a month and as you can see in the first two columns the **Hotel Name = "Hilton"** in **Location = "London"** is supervised twice but have different Date values. What I want to do is add a new column called **"IS Duplicate"** and populate it with a **"duplicate"** or **"Not Duplicate"** value based on similarities on **Report type** and **Location** column values even though **Date** value is different. (See table below)

[image]

Can you help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: mysql != google-bigquery. Please retain only the relevant tag.

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 you can use `COUNT` over `Report Type, Location` and mark the rows that have a value >1. Other databases have window and ranking functions too. MySQL though only added them in v 8.0

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, the fields you use to determine a duplicate are Report type, Location and Hotel name, right ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes that is correct.

Comment: @GMB I am using google-bigquery

Comment: No YEAR part needed?

Comment: @Harun - what is the data type of Date field? is it String or Date?

Comment: @jarlh Yes not needed

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant It is string

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by location, date_trunc(date, month)) > 1
             then 'Duplicate' else 'Not Duplicate'
        end) as is_duplicate
from t;
```

I would recommend removing the `case` and just keeping this as a boolean value, `true` or `false`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for the answer but what if the Date column is a string as opposed to Date?

Comment: @Harun . . . Then you would convert it to a date or use string operations to identify the month.  You should fix your data so dates are not stored as strings, though.  BigQuery has lots of support for date/time data and you should take advantage of that.